# Replacing header contents with empty string in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a code to remove the text which is in head tag. Soup us the html of a website

```
    for link in soup.findAll('head'):
        link.replaceWith("")
```

I am trying to replace the entire content with "". However this is not working. How can i remove all text between head tags from soup completely.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[head.extract() for head in soup.findAll('head')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use """ (3 quotes), where you appear to be using only two.

Example:

```
"""
This block
is commented out
"""
```

Happy coding!

EDIT: This is not what the user was asking, my apologies.

I'm not experienced with Beautiful Soup, but I found a snippet of code on SO that might work for you ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964459/how-to-remove-text-between-script-and-script-using-python)):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.lower())
to_extract = soup.findAll('ahref') #Edit the stuff inside '' to change which tag you want items to be removed from, like 'ahref' or 'head'
for item in to_extract:
    item.extract()
```

By the look of it, it *might* just remove every link on your page, though.

I'm sorry if this doesn't help you more!

Comment: Oh! Oh, I understand now. I'm revising my answer, my apologies.